# How to add PFObjects to a tableview in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I am building a checkin app, and am having trouble filling my tableview with guests stored using Parse. I get an error when trying to append the objects. I also have a user login that I followed from a Udemy course. In the course he showed how to display PFUsers, but I can't get it to work using PFObjects. Any help would be great on this.

Here is the working code with PFUsers.

```
var users = [""]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFUser.query()

    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        for object in objects! {

            var user:PFUser = object as! PFUser

            self.users.append(user.username!)

        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })

}
```

And here is the nonworking code with PFObjects.

```
var users = [""]

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "TestObject")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        for object in objects! {

            var guest = object as! PFObject

            self.users.append(guest.foo!)
        }

    })
}
```

The error shows on the line

```
self.users.append(guest.foo!)
```

And the error says "'PFObject' does not have a member named 'foo'"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to get the object label as a string before I could append it to the array to then add it to the tableview.

Here is the working code:

```
var users = [""]

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "TestObject")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        for object in objects! {

            var foo = object.objectForKey("foo") as? String

            self.users.append(foo!)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You define your PFUser object with the variable `user`, this will make the first example work (you get the `name` of the user)  The second example doesn’t work cause you still define the PFObject as `user` but try to access the `name` of `guest` which is not defined.

You could either go with the first example or change

```
var user:PFObject = object as! PFObject
```

With

```
var guest:PFObject = object as! PFObject
```

Either way, it doesn’t matter for your code, it is just the name of the variable.
This explanation will fix your “Use of unresolved identifier ‘guest’”
But this isn’t your only problem,
the PFUser object which the first example uses is a special kind of a PFObject, the PFUser class does have a `.name` which refers to (obviously) the name of the user. Not every PFObject has a name though so you can’t just access the `.name` of a PFObject. Parse has an excellent [documentation about retrieving objects](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-retrieving/iOS) I would first access this documentation. If this is still unclear to you, you can open another specific question about your new problem.

To retreive the data from an object you need to use `[]`

Let’s suggest we have a class named `gameScore` with the following info

```
score: 1337, playerName: “Sean Plott”, cheatMode: false
```

We would do that as follows

```
var gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
gameScore["score"] = 1337
gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott"
gameScore["cheatMode"] = false
gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if (success) {
    // The object has been saved.
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }     
}
```

To retrieve the object you need to query (as you already did in your post) 
Ones you’ve received the data you can extract it as follows:

```
let score = gameScore["score"] as Int
let playerName = gameScore[“playerName"] as String
let cheatMode = gameScore["cheatMode"] as Bool
```

Comment: Would it matter how the objects are created? Because for the users I created them in the app, but for the guests I imported a csv file of all the guests into parse.

Comment: A PFObject can’t be converted to a PFUser. You would need to convert the data of the cvs file to a PFUser. If you create a PFUser for your users which you created in the app, but a PFObject for the guests you can’t (properly and easily) exchange data between the 2

Comment: Yeah I only want to see the guest. I can't get the retrieving objects to work from parse. But I'll keep trying. Thanks @milo526

Comment: For the consistency and quality of the SO questions, would you please mark this answer as answering your question and create a new question regarding your problem with the PFObject

Comment: But my question is still the same. How to get PFObjects into the tableview?

Comment: If that was the original intent of your question, it was unclear. The error message and mentioning of the error in your question regarded that you wanted that error to be resolved. You now edited your question but it still looks like you want to resolve the error. Not how to add the data to your tableview. The question is unclear, these are 2 very specific problems and should be separate questions

Comment: But the error would fix the problem adding it to the tableview wouldn't it?

Comment: A PFObject is (at it states) an object. It can’t be added to the tableview. A PFObject does indeed not have a member named foo. Read the parse documentation. It is EXCELLENT and will solve your problem in a few seconds. I’ll even provide you the link [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects/iOS)

Comment: @ffhooper Although it is against the standard SO rules. here is your answer